# Pass Paramater in Form action in Mvc4

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Am using mvc4, I have jquery where am calling upload action 
if i call the method (Upload) with No Parameter it work fine

Using **action="Upload"**

but I want to pass Parameter so I try this and is not working :
**action="Upload?id=' + data.record.ID +'"**

How to use action to pass parameter ?
here my code:

```
     UplodedFiles: {
                    title: 'Uploded Files',
                    type: 'file',
                    input: function (data) {
                        return '<form target="iframeTarget" class="formUploadFile" action="Upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <input type="file" onchange="this.form.submit()" name="myFile"/> </form> <iframe class="upload-iframe" style="display: none;" src="#" name="iframeTarget"></iframe>';
                    },
                    list:false,
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Upload(int id)
    {
        string upload_dir = Server.MapPath("~/app_data/Uploded/");

        foreach (string f in Request.Files.Keys)
        {
            if (Request.Files[f].ContentLength > 0)
            {
                //System.IO.File.SetCreationTime(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploded/" + Request.Files[f].FileName), DateTime.Now);
                Request.Files[f].SaveAs(upload_dir + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[f].FileName));




                using (ProjectContext ProjectContext = new ProjectContext())
                {
                    var p = _db.Projects.Find(id);
                    p.UplodedFiles += Request.Files[f].FileName + '#';
                    ProjectContext.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }

        return RedirectToRoute(new { Action = "Index", Controller = "Projects" });
    }
```

Comment: We need to see the code that makes the call, and the code that receives it. I don't see the code that makes the call.

Comment: this (action="Upload") is making the call ,if the controller upload is with empty parameter ,and it works. But with Parameter no !